# How to stream a file directly to S3 in C# without saving locally first

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-sdk

I'm new to .Net programming and have been wrestling with how to stream a file from C# (DOTNETCORE 2.+) to S3 without saving it locally.

Here's the use case:

Be able to submit a query to SQL server and extract a GZipped, delimited file to an S3 bucket.  This will need to be coded in .NETCORE since the ultimate goal is to run it in a Linux Docker Container.

Constraints - There will be limited disk space and memory, so saving a large file locally then moving it to S3 is not an option.

The following code is a snippet from my .NETCORE console app that writes a sqldatareader's data to a zipped stream to a local file:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(filepath + filename + fileextension))
        using (GZipStream compress = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(compress))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Object[] row = new Object[dr.FieldCount];

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dr.GetValues(row);
                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(delimiter, row));
            }
        }
```

The .NETCORE AWSSDK used to expose an Amazon.S3.IO class that I could have used for the outFile filestream, but AWS decided not to release it to .NETCORE 2.+. AWS says use the AmazonS3Client or TransferUtility.  However, I can't find an example on how to upload a stream without a local file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I wound up creating a class that returned a stream defaulted to 10 MB while using the S3 multipart upload API. In that class, a memory stream is used, so, disk and memory can be controlled.

Comment: source will be great!

Comment: Do you have example of code that you could share of how to do this?