# How can I stream a massive object directly to S3, without a MemoryStream or local file?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to write a massive object to AWS S3 (e.g. 25 GB).

Currently I can get it working in two ways:

- Write the content to a file on local disk, then send the file to S3 using [multi-part upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html)
- Write the content to a `MemoryStream`, then send that stream to S3 using multi-part upload

However, I don't like either approach, because I need to reserve a large amount of disk space or memory for the operation. I am generating this content in code, so I was hoping to open a stream to an S3 object, and generate the content directly to that object. But I can't see how to make that work.

Is it possible to build a massive object in S3 without representing the entire object in a local file or memory first?

(Note: My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49989707), but that question doesn't have a useful answer.)

Comment: Open a stream to the large amount of data, read a small chunk of data from the stream, write the small chunk to the other stream, repeat. Probably you can just read/write a single byte at a time if you want an easy life; the rest of the IO system will buffer the data, so you don't need to get funky with your own c# having byte[] buffers

Comment: @CaiusJard I got something working based on your comment. I posted my solution as an answer to this question. Does that look right to you? (Conceptually what you said makes perfect sense; I was just hung up on how exactly to implement that.)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by breaking the overall payload into chunks, and sending each individual chunk as a separate `MemoryStream`.

Technically this solution still uses a `MemoryStream`, but that's OK, since I can control how much memory is used by adjusting the chunk size. For my test, I created a 25GB file while keeping memory usage well below that (~2 GB IIRC).

Here is my solution:

```cs
private const string BucketName = "YOUR-BUCKET-NAME-HERE";
private static readonly RegionEndpoint BucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
private const string Key = "massive-file-test";

// We're going to send 100 chunks of 256 MB each, for a total of 25 GB.
// The content will be the asterisk ("*") repeated for the desired size.
private const int ChunkSizeMb = 256;
private const int TotalSizeGb = 25;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Writing object to {BucketName}, {Key}");

    int totalChunks = TotalSizeGb * 1024 / ChunkSizeMb;
    int chunkSizeBytes = ChunkSizeMb * 1024 * 1024;
    string payload = new String('*', chunkSizeBytes);

    // Initiate the request.
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = BucketName,
        Key = Key
    };

    List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();
    IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(BucketRegion);
    InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse = s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);

    // Open a stream to build the input.
    for (int i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++)
    {
        // Write the next chunk to the input stream.
        Console.WriteLine($"Writing chunk {i} of {totalChunks}");
        using (var stream = ToStream(payload))
        {
            // Write the next chunk to s3.
            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
            {
                BucketName = BucketName,
                Key = Key,
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                PartNumber = i + 1,
                PartSize = chunkSizeBytes,
                InputStream = stream,
            };

            uploadResponses.Add(s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest));
        }
    }

    // Complete the request.
    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = BucketName,
        Key = Key,
        UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
    };

    completeRequest.AddPartETags(uploadResponses);
    s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);

    Console.WriteLine("Script is complete. Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static Stream ToStream(string s)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Even with this it means you have to make a 256 mb string, then copy it into a memory stream, and if you have multiples of these then it's burning a huge amount of memory for no real reason; write your own stream

Comment: Oh.. I see AnonCoward has taken that approach but not finished the stream class off - just add the missing methods/properties to make it seekable

Answer (score 1):

Here is what AnonCoward started, finished off by adding seeking - it's a trivial op for a stream that does nothing except write asterisks to its buffer. If you were generating more complex data it would be hard work but for seeking all you need to do is set the position and say "yep, done that" because no matter where you seek to in the stream the behavior of creating asterisks is always the same

```cs
class AsteriskGeneratingStream : Stream
{
    long _pos = 0;
    long _length = 0;
    public AsteriskGeneratingStream(long length)
    {
        _length = length;
    }
    public override long Length => _length;

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // Create the data as needed
        if (count + _pos > _length)
            count = (int)(_length - _pos);
        
        for (int i = offset; i < count; i++)
            buffer[i] = (byte)'*';
        
        _pos += count;
        return count;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    { 
        if(origin == SeekOrigin.Begin) //lets just trust that the caller will be sensible and not set e.g. negative offset
            _pos = offset;
        else if(origin == SeekOrigin.Current)
            _pos += offset;
        else if(origin == SeekOrigin.End)
            _pos = _length + offset;

        return _pos;
    }

    public override bool CanSeek => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Position { get => _pos; set => _pos = value; }
    public override void Flush() { }
    public override void SetLength(long value) { _length = value; }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long objectSize = 25L * 1024 * 1024;
        var s3 = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
        var xfer = new TransferUtility(s3,new TransferUtilityConfig
        {
            MinSizeBeforePartUpload = 5L * 1024 * 1024
        });

        var helper = new AsteriskGeneratingStream(objectSize);
        xfer.Upload(helper, "bucket-name", "object-key");
    }
}
```

Note, I can't guarantee it'll work right off the bat because I'm on a cellphone and can't test this via c# fiddle but let's see how it blows up!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Of course, my actual use case is more complex than the asterisk example. I don't know the content length up front, so it's not clear to me how to implement a seekable Stream. I'll do some research on that and maybe ask a new question.

Comment: You only need to know the length up front if it's relevant to the data, and if S3 will even call to seek using the End as a reference.. Though it's not quite clear to me how you can hope to upload a file of size X if you never know X - surely someone/thing, somewhere in the system, must know X

Answer (score 0):

If you can create the object on the fly, or at least cache fairly small segments, you can create a stream that serves the data up to S3.  Note, that unless you can also create any part of the object out of order, you need to prevent the AWS SDK from using a multi-part upload, which will slow down the transfer speed.

```
    class DataStream : Stream
    {
        long _pos = 0;
        long _length = 0;
        public DataStream(long length)
        {
            _length = length;
        }
        public override long Length => _length;

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            // Create the data as needed, on demand
            // For this example, just cycle through 0 to 256 in the data over and over again
            if (count + _pos > _length)
            {
                count = (int)(_length - _pos);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                buffer[i + offset] = (byte)((_pos + i) % 256);
            }
            _pos += count;
            return count;
        }

        public override bool CanRead => true;

        // Stub out all other methods.  For a seekable stream
        // Seek() and Postion need to be implemented, along with CanSeek changed
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override bool CanSeek => false;
        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override long Position { get => _pos; set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override void Flush() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override void SetLength(long value) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long objectSize = 25L * 1024 * 1024;
            var s3 = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
            // Prevent a multi-part upload, which requires a seekable stream
            var xfer = new TransferUtility(s3, new TransferUtilityConfig
            {
                MinSizeBeforePartUpload = objectSize + 1
            });

            var helper = new DataStream(objectSize);
            xfer.Upload(helper, "bucket-name", "object-key");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution looks promising, but unfortunately does not work for me. When I try to create a 25 GB file, I get an S3Exception `Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size`. Looks like max 5GB per upload. When I adjusted the `MinSizeBeforePartUpload` to stay under the 5GB limit (still 25GB overall), then I get a different error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Base stream of PartialWrapperStream must be seekable'`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized shortly after I posted it won't work with sizes over 5gb.  As I say, you need to add the seeking related methods to your stream implementation, and be able to handle arbitrary seeks.  And on top of it, you also need to support seeks to go backwards if a part fails to upload.  So, unless your stream creation method supports of all that like my trivial case in the example, it's probably just not workable.

Comment: I'll leave the answer up here in case it's useful to others, but hopefully someone can come up with a simpler case for you.

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I'd take. @srk just implement seeking on the stream - it's not difficult - when told to seek just set the `_pos` accordingly for whatever origin is passed in